# Handle servletrequest asynchronously to respond back to client quickly and process the bulky tasks in background on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlet-3.0

I have a servlet that sends multiple mails to different addresses when a client requests it.

Since the sending of mail takes a long time, the client has to wait before the he receives the response. I want to handle the sending of mails asynchronously to send the response back to the client faster.

Also the sending of mails can be delayed to few minutes and need not be realtime. 
I don't want to save any info in the DB and want to handle this within application only.The solution that is coming in my mind is as follows:

When the client request this servlet, the servlet will add the mailing list and the contents as an attribute in the ServletContext and send the response back to client
Have a helper servlet thats gets loaded on startup and spawn a timertask thread that executes after every (say) 10 minutes, read the servletcontext attributes, send mails and remove the attribute.

Please suggest if this is a good solution. Also propose a better one if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution sounds reasonable, except that I would just launch a mailer thread every time a request comes. There is no need to have a separate "helper" servlet just for this reason.

Or even better, have a [thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and submit a [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) for every request.

Just be extra careful on thread/thread pool options: make sure they finish sending all emails on (graceful) Tomcat shutdown. Tomcat shutdown should only finish after all emails are sent.